# Java (Sum Odd Numbers and Compute Average)

Tags: java

I cannot figure this out..

```
//Modify the following to sum only the odd numbers from 1 to 100, and compute the average. (Hint: n is an odd number if n % 2 is not 0.)
    sum=0;
    for (int number = 1; number <= 100; ++number) { // for loop
         sum += number;     // same as "sum = sum + number"
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: The comment tells you what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test if the number is odd and count how many odds you find.

```
int oddCount = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int number = 1; number <= 100; ++number) { // for loop
  if (number % 2 != 0) {
     sum += number;
     oddCount++;
  }
}
System.out.println(sum / (double) oddCount)
```

Or, skip the even values with something like

```
int oddCount = 0;
int sum = 0;
for (int number = 1; number <= 100; number += 2) { // <-- skip the even values.
  sum += number;
  oddCount++;
}
System.out.println(sum / (double) oddCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that odd numbers have a remainder of 1 when divided by 2, you don't need an if statement:

```
int oddCount = 0, sum = 0;
for (int n = 1; n <= 100; ++n) { // for loop
    oddCount += n % 2;
    sum += n * (n % 2);
}
System.out.println(sum / (double) oddCount)
```

The trick here is that `n % 2` is zero for even numbers, they have no effect on the totals, but for odd numbers it's 1, so that makes them count.